# how to do fourier frequency matrix multiplication if size is different?

Tags: math, fft

sorry this is not a program issue.

I just get confused for this Theory:

The FFT of a convolution is equal to the multiplication of their own's FFT.

i.e.:

**FFT(conv(x,y)) = FFT(x) * FFT(y)**

**for the left side:**
lets say i have a image with 100x100 size and kernel 3x3, if I convolve, i will get a matrix of 98x98, then its FFT will also be 98x98

**for the right side:**
if I take FFT for each I will get a frequency matrix of 3x3 and 100x100 respectively.

Then how should i do the multiplication? Some of you may say we can pad the 3x3 kernel to 100x100 and take FFT, but still we will get a matrix of 100x100 instead of 98x98?

Can someone give me some hints?

Comment: Pad the smaller image with zeroes to make it the same size as the larger image. (This also helps to avoid circular convolution.)

Comment: Please also note that this question really belongs on http://dsp.stackexchange.com, not here.

Answer (score 0):

A convolution of two signals of size `L` and `P` respectively will have a result of size `N = L + N - 1`.
Therefore, the mathematically correct implementation of **conv(x,y)** will have size 102x102. You should zero pad to both x and y to make them of size 102.

When you perform the convolution as CNN convolution layers does (which is what I think you are doing) without any zero padding, you are actually cropping the result (you are leaving outside the border results).
Therefore, you can just do a 102x102 fft result and crop accordingly for the 98x98 result (crop 2 at the start and 2 and the end).

**ATTENTION:** Unlike how zero padding usually works for Convolutional layers, for this case add zeros at the **END**. If not, you will be adding a shift that will be reflected in a shift in the output. ex. the expected result could be `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and if you apply 1 zero at the beggining and 1 at the end (instead of 2 at the end) you will have `[4, 1, 2, 3]`.

**ATTENTION 2:** Not making the sizes to 102 when using iff(fft()) technique will produce something call *Aliasing*. This will make for example, an expected result of `30, 31, 57, 47, 87, 47, 33, 27, 5` to be `77, 64, 84, 52, 87`. Note this results is actually product of making:

```
  30, 31, 57, 47, 87 
+ 47, 33, 27, 5
--------------------
  77, 64, 84, 52, 87
```